# Bash dialog command -- why don't bottom and right borders respect dialogrc colors?

Tags: bash, colors, dialog

I'm trying to format my `dialog` boxes using DIALOGRC; I have most of it working fine, however the dialog windows seem to have an issue with their border where the bottom and right borders don't respect the `border_color` setting in my DIALOGRC file.

I've made sure that the `DIALOGRC` variable is available and pointing to the appropriate file, and have verified it's active by changing other colors in the specified file. However, no matter what I do, I can't seem to get the bottom/right borders to get with the program.

Here's an excerpt of my DIALOGRC file:

```
use_shadow = OFF
# tried use_shadow = ON, no difference
use_colors = ON
screen_color = (WHITE,BLACK,OFF)
shadow_color = (BLACK,BLACK,OFF)
dialog_color = (BLUE,BLACK,ON)
title_color = (RED,BLACK,ON)
border_color = (RED,BLACK,OFF)
button_active_color = (RED,RED,ON)
button_inactive_color = (RED,BLACK,OFF)
button_key_active_color = (WHITE,RED,ON)
button_key_inactive_color = (RED,BLACK,ON)
button_label_active_color = button_active_color
button_label_inactive_color = button_inactive_color
```

(with the various specific options omitted for brevity -- but none of them specify WHITE as a background color, so...?)

With this file, when I run the following command:

`dialog --title " Test " --yesno "\n Hello, this is my test dialog.\n\n As you can see, I have my border set to (RED,BLACK,OFF).\n Yet for some reason, the bottom and right borders are stuck\n on white-on-black?" 20 80`

And it produces this atrociously-framed window:

[image: dialog with white-on-black bottom and right borders]

I've tried changing the `use_shadow` option, and I've tried with the `--shadow` and `--no-shadow` parameters for shiggles, but neither (nor lack of either) changes the output. I haven't had luck searching this on Google, partially because the command "dialog" is woefully generic and gets me all sorts of answers for all sorts of unrelated stuff.

As per @K7AAY, this occurs on Ubuntu 18.04.2 with dialog version 1.3-20171209; I've also reproduced it on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS with dialog version 1.3-20160209 and of note, when I installed dialog on a Debian 10u1 system (dialog version 1.3-20190211). None of the outstanding bug reports for dialog on Debian (which if I understand correctly is where the package is primarily maintained?) have anything to do with colors or borders, let alone border colors.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: I just scanned through the yad manual and I don't see anything about border colors. In general, yad has more bells and whistles than other dialog managers and even it doesn't appear to have what you want. It does support images and some HTML markup within the dialogs which would let you introduce color within the dialog box.

Comment: @Joe `dialog` *has* border colors; the red borders on the top/left are respecting the settings in the config, but the bottom/right are stuck on the defaults (black on white)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to `border_color`, you should also set `border2_color`. If you want them to use the same colors, you can simply add the following line to your `.dialogrc` file:

```
border2_color = border_color
```

This should be done for any other borders you customize, too. For example:

```
menubox_border_color = (RED,BLACK,OFF)
menubox_border2_color = menubox_border_color
```

Comment: I'd give you a bounty if I could but apparently I don't have enough rep here or something  FWIW, to anyone else looking for this, all `*border*` options seem to have a `border2` counterpart, e.g. `menubox_border_color` → `menubox_border2_color`!

Comment: Thanks, @DoktorJ! I'll add a note about that to my answer. And no worries, I'm not a bounty hunter! ;) I'm just glad I could help.